# Hystrix Dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, hystrix

I'm completly new about Hystrix, however I need to monitor metrics from it.

So far I got a stand alone that display/run the Hystrix Dashboard.

In my project I add the dependencies;

```
compile(group:"com.netflix.hystrix", name:"hystrix-metrics-event-stream", version:'1.5.5')
compile(group:"org.springframework.cloud", name:"spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard", version:'1.1.5.RELEASE')
compile(group:"org.springframework.boot", name:"spring-boot-starter-actuator", version:'1.4.0.RELEASE')
compile(group:"org.springframework.cloud", name:"spring-cloud-starter-hystrix", version:'1.1.5.RELEASE')
```

Also in my SpringConfig I add

```
@EnableHystrix
public class MyAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new HystrixMetricsStreamServlet(), "/hystrix.stream"); 
        return registration;
    }
}
```

I succesfully boot the services I can check if it is running by localhost:8080/health and get the answer.

When I add localhost:8080/hystrix.stream and hit the button Monitor Streams in the Hystrix Dashboard for a brief time it says "Loading..." but then I get "Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream."

Also I got this in the dashboard console;

```
17:19:26.858 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  c.g.k.h.c.s.d.HystrixDashboardProxyConnectionHandler - Proxing request to http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream
17:19:31.879 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR c.g.k.h.c.s.d.HystrixDashboardProxyConnectionHandler - Proxying request
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The timeout period of 5000ms has been exceeded
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.timeout(HttpClientRequestBase.java:155)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.handleTimeout(HttpClientRequestBase.java:140)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.lambda$setTimeout$0(HttpClientRequestBase.java:100)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:782)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:753)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:440)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:19:31.894 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR c.g.k.h.c.s.d.HystrixDashboardProxyConnectionHandler - Proxying request
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Connection was closed
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientConnection.handleClosed(ClientConnection.java:396)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:314)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:190)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelInactive(VertxHandler.java:97)
```

Finally trying to make a curl localhost:8080/hystrix.stream isn't responding at all.

I'm not sure if missing something anyone could give me a hint please?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing @HistrixDashBoard annotation over your main class

Comment: That should be in the main class? or should be in the config class?

By the way, I got an stand alone app for the dashboard, so that annotation should be in the client app? or in the dashboard app?

Comment: My bad :) annotation is @EnableHystrix on your main class and you should also have spring-actutator if you are using springboot. I think the annotation should be on the client application. Even I’m new to hystrix.

Comment: Nope isn't working, added Annotations SpringBootApplication, EnableCircuitBreaker, EnableHystrixDashboard, EnableHystrix and isn't working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using actuator, your stream should be here:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream